# django custom template tags: render method not called

Tags: django, django-templates

payment-tags.py

```
@register.simple_tag
def has_purchased(user_id):
  payments = Payment.objects.all(user__id=user_id)
  return PaymentObjects(payments)

class PaymentObjects(template.Node):
  def __init__(self, payments):
    print 'inside init'
    self.payments_obj = payments

  def render(self, context):
    print 'inside render'
    context['payments'] = self.payments_obj
    return ''
```

Indside html:

```
{% load payment-tags %}
{% has_purchased request.user.id %}
```

The render method of PaymentObjects class never get called, It goes inside the init function but not inside render..

I had searched this issue on google but didn't got any satisfactory answer which can solve the issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register.simple_tag` is used for tag functions that immediately return the result (Django creates the node for you). If you want to return your own node, use `register.tag` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But in that case how should I send the parameter which I need to send i.e. request.user.id, as when I change it to tag it gives error "has_purchased() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: @Neo: You need to parse the arguments yourself. Tags get two arguments, `parser` and `token`. [Read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags).

Comment: You will face the same problem if you try to load it from a template that has been rendered from a view. It somehow only works with included and extended templates.  I faced this issue, what I did was to load it from the base template which will be later extended by all other templates.